# Prove that $\textbf{II}_p\equiv0$ on $M:=f(U)$ if and only if $M$ is contained in a plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

> Let $U\subset\mathbb R^2$ be open and connected, and let $\ f:U\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ be the parametrization of a regular surface. Prove that $\textbf{II}_p\equiv0$ on $M:=f(U)$ if and only if $M$ is contained in a plane
>
> (where, $\textbf{II}_p$ is the second fundamental form)

$\textbf{My attempt}$

$''\Rightarrow''$

Let $\textbf{II}_p\equiv0$, then

$f_{uu}\cdot\ n=0$$\qquad$$f_{uv}\cdot\ n=0$$\qquad$$f_{vv}\cdot\ n=0$$\qquad$ since $n$ is nonzero vector

$f_{uu}=0$ this implies $\ f_u$ is constant (the other cases analogue)

so $f(u,v)=su+tv$ ($s,t$ constants) and this is a subset of a plane ?

Answer (score 1):

From your proof, you only get $f_{uu}, f_{uv}, f_{vv}$ are orthogonal to $\vec n$, and $\vec n$ is a priori not a constant vector in $\mathbb R^3$. Moreover, it is impossible to obtain $f_{uv} = f_{uu} = f_{vv}=0$, for example, take $g: U \to U$ be any diffeomorphism and $f = i\circ g$, where $i(x, y) = (x, y, 0)$.

A standard proof is to consider geodesics. Try to show that a geodesic in $f(U)$ is also a geodesic in $\mathbb R^3$. What is the geodesic in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I don't know the term geodesic. But i think to prove is, that n is constant. Since $n=\frac{f_u\times f_v}{|f_u\times f_v|}$ from the equation $f_{uu}\cdotp n=0$ we obtain:   $f_{uu}$ is linearly independent of either $f_u$ or $f_v$, say $f_u$ 

and $f_{vv}$ is linearly independent of either $f_u$ or $f_v$, say $f_v$ then we're done 

if this is not so, we have to consider also $f_{uv}$ and eliminate impossible cases.

Comment: From your comment I just realized that actually one can show that $n$ is a constant vector: write $f_{uu}\cdot n = -(f_u \cdot n_u)$ and similarly for $f_{uv}$ and $f_{vv}$.